# Geting indicator value for other timeframe

Tags: trading, pine-script

I am using pine-script to plot the distance from the open to daily Average True Range on an intraday chart. However, when i use an intraday chart the value for atr is not calculated with daily values

```
d_open = security(tickerid, "D", open)

atr_l1 = d_open - vatr
atrLow =plot(title='atr_l1', series=atr_l1, style=circles, color=lime)
```

This code plots the ATR based on selected time frame

I would like to access the daily ATR regardless to selected timeframe

```
dayAtr10() => atr(10)
dailyAtr = security(tickerid, "D", dayAtr10())
```

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass all daily calculations to the `security()` call, and use `security()` in a way that will not repaint. See the PineCoders [How to avoid repainting when using security() - PineCoders FAQ](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) indicator for an explanation on how to use `security()` while avoiding repainting.

This script shows both repainting and non-repainting methods of using `security()`. If you leave it on a chart for a while, you will see the discrepancies between both.

```
//@version=3
study("", "", true)
atrGap = open - atr(10)
d_openGap = security(tickerid, "D", atrGap)
plot(d_openGap, "d_openGap", red)
d_openGapNoRepaint = security(tickerid, "D", atrGap[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(d_openGapNoRepaint, "d_openGap", green)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted. How do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: Click the check mark under the up/down vote arrows for the answer.